# Duplicated post requests protection, multithreading

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate, duplicates

Have Spring Boot application.
Controller->Service->Repository

Problem: if user send several **post** requests to server, each of them creates its own thread.

And **@Service** checks like below - don't work:

```
    @Service
    @Transactional
    public class MyService {
      public List<SingleRecord> save( List<SingleRecord> recs, Integer userId){
    
          List<SingleRecord> recsFromDataBase = singleRecordRepository.findAllByUserId(userId);
          if ( recsFromDataBase.size() > 0 ){
              throw new MyException("User already has records!");
          } else {
              return singleRecordRepository.saveAll(recs);
          }
        
      }
    }
```

For example: we have 10 post simultaneous requests from user. (he put button 'Send' 10 times, during connection problems ) They all reach `singleRecordRepository.saveAll(recs);` and all persist to base. (because of multithreading)
So service checks became useless.

I tried to use *Serializable* for **@Transactional** isolation level - but it cause massive amount deadlocks and errors during separate users work with this service.

Java articles authors suggest to use tokens for post requests - this is not look like graceful solution.

Now I'm going to create thread safe Singleton to check if user requests are duplicated. This is awful...

How to make service check works properly?

---

https://github.com/PilVadim/FSStackOverflow

Example of service that works same as my app.
To reproduce the error:

1. Start app. Open swagger UI http://localhost:8085/swagger-ui.html#
2. For Chrome - F12->Network->change 'Online' to 'GPRS';
3. On swagger ui, open POST request, change `id` in body to null, and press 'Execute' several times;
4. Change 'GPRS' back to 'Online';
   Almost all request will complete successfully.
   That is mean - check in service doesn't work correctly.

Comment: You should make your service idempotent. This means you should be able to handle that records are already created.

Comment: @Simon Martinelli, but how? Is there any best practices?

Comment: No this depends on your requirements. What is SingleRecord? Can it be identified by I unique identifier? Then you could use Merge instead of Insert

Comment: Yes, It has one unique identifier. It is surrogate key and they are all null in users request. How Spring find out that objects with empty id are one object? For merge work we need composite key consisting of all fields.

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem, why not simply disable the button when it is first pressed?

Comment: @Lino - fine solution, but I want solve it by java

Comment: @VadimPilipenko Could you please share the class definition with all relevant fields of `SingleRecord` and if possible the input JSON? It would make understanding your problem a lot easier

Comment: @Lino, sorry, can't show you all logic, only rough description. SingleRecord has simple structure, like - 
class SingleRecord  {
Integer id; 
String content;}

Comment: @Lino, real problem is that I java app doesn't distinguish duplicated requests from same user. Maybe I should look inside transaction?

Comment: @VadimPilipenko providing a [mre] is the best option for you if you want to get your problem solved, it doesn't require you to provide company specific data or therelike, but some meaningful mock data is fine

Comment: @VadimPilipenko Transactions are **per request** and not **per user** so that doesn't work, you need to simply have an `findByRecord()` method in the repository, which returns the record from the DB which is equal to the one passed to it (excluding the ID field)

Comment: @Lino, ok, I will make mock app today and share with you

Comment: @VadimPilipenko well it must not exactly be an entire app, but simply showing an example of a `class` and some data would be enough, it is currently the only missing information from your question

Comment: @Lino, done. Hope it helps to understand my problem

Answer (score 0):

changed

`public List<SingleRecord> save( List<SingleRecord> recs, Integer userId)`

to

`public synchronized List<SingleRecord> save( List<SingleRecord> recs, Integer userId)`

Added **synchronized** before `save`
Now only 1 thread can get access into service.

Everything started to work as planned.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use annotation on your repository method:

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
List<SingleRecord> findAllByUserId(Long userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

- I think you can set unique key for field user_id in table
  SingleRecord.
- I think it is simple and useful.
- You can read more detail in below link:
  https://dev.to/manjufy/rest-api-how-to-avoid-duplicate-resource-creation-on-concurrent-requests-o23